# How to correctly use real-time Symfony Process Output

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-process

I have following Symfony Process which calls a standard `git clone` command and writes the output in real-time:

```
$process = new Process(
    [
        'git',
        'clone',
        self::REPOSITORY_URL . $project . '.git',
        $destinationPath
    ]
);

$cli = $this->cli;
$process->run(static function ($type, $buffer) use ($cli) {
    if(Process::ERR === $type) {
        $cli->error($buffer);
    } else {
        $cli->print($buffer);
    }
});
```

What I get is the output `Cloning into '/my/projects/project'...`, but formatted as an error.

I was able to pinpoint, that `$type` always has the value `'err'`, even during non-error output.

I had this problem before, when I used `$process->start()` first. Apparently, the process was not considered as finished, therefore I could solve it with `$process->wait()`. But I didn't get the output in real-time, thus the usage of `$process->run()` now. I feel like there might be a way to work with `wait()` again, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: The symfony process doc say you must disable PHP output_buffering directive or use obs_flush function to force sending output buffer.

Comment: @Francisco I tried both methods with no success. Adding ob_flush() after the output functions also threw the error `Failed to flush buffer. No buffer to flush`.

Comment: The same. Tried everything possible! Does not work!